# Using for_each on property of a counted resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a resource with a varying count (0 or 1 resources).

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  count = local.acm_version_count

  domain_name               = "${local.deployment_version_name}.example.com"
  subject_alternative_names = [
    "*.${local.deployment_version_name}.example.com
  ]

  validation_method = "DNS"
}
```

And now I want to iterate over a property of the optional resource:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "acm_validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.r53_zone.zone_id
  name    = each.value.name
  type    = each.value.type
  ttl     = 60

  records = [each.value.record]

  allow_overwrite = true

}
```

Of course, because `aws_acm_certificate.cert` is counted, we must access that at an index (i.e., `aws_acm_certificate.cert[0]` or `aws_acm_certificate.cert[count.index]`). However, I can't use a count because it is mutually exclusive from `for_each`, and I cannot access `[0]` when the optional resource is not created. Ideally I could add a count on the record itself, so that I ignore the `aws_route53_record.acm_validation` if there is no `aws_acm_certificate`

I know about `toproduct`, so I wonder if that would be useful - but I honestly didn't know enough about it to utilize it and couldn't make it work here

How can I iterate over this optional resource so that I can ignore it if the acm is optionally excluded, but still iterate over those `domain_validation_options` if there is an acm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce a flattened list of all of the "domain validation options" across all of the `aws_acm_certificate.cert` instances like this:

```
flatten(aws_acm_certificate.cert[*].domain_validation_options)
```

When you have zero certificates declared, this would be like calling `flatten([])` and so it'll just produce an empty list, whereas when `count` is nonzero it'll capture all of the declared validation options, because `aws_acm_certificate.cert[*].domain_validation_options` alone would produce a list of lists of objects.

I think it should work to insert that `flatten( ... )` call in the same place where you are currently referring directly to an attribute of a singleton resource, and leave everything else unchanged:

```
  for_each = {
    for dvo in flatten(aws_acm_certificate.cert[*].domain_validation_options) :
    dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }
```

In most cases I'd suggest thinking of a conditional count as "there can be zero or more instances", even if you know that the maximum count is `1` really, because the language features designed for working with lists of objects are often more compact and concise than what you'd need to write to specifically distinguish between *zero or one* of some resource. It doesn't always work out like that, but in many cases it's not really important whether there's one or more than one instances, including this situation.

Comment: Both answers are excellent, and this one is the most simple for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked for me. Been trying out so many things since 48 hours and this one fixed :) Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the resource is created, and pass an empty list to `for_each` if it isn't. I would add a `local` variable to make this a bit cleaner.

```
locals {
  dvos = local.acm_version_count == 0 ? [] : aws_acm_certificate.cert[0].domain_validation_options
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "acm_validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in local.dvos : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  ...
}
```